# How does one control a plane in GTA San Andreas on Android?

Tags: android, grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

How does one control a plane in GTA San Andreas on Android (with the touch interface)? The virtual joystick is hard to control precisely, but so far (before the flying school) it was used only for walking and a little for swimming, so it was fine. Is there a way to control going up and down (pitch) separately from turning left and right (roll and yaw)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way you can do this is if you use a compatible bluetooth controller with seperate analogue sticks, these unfortunately arent widely available and also arent always compatible with every device.

Just using the touch interface there is no way to control them seperately, which does make flying somewhat awful i will agree with you.

The company that makes the openPandora console have also made such a controller which i have used on android but like i had said previously good controllers are not widely available.

Can also say with iOS that when Jailbroken you can use certain bluetooth controllers like PS3 and Wii which is quite fun

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is a bummer, with all the customization available for the touch controls for driving, I was expecting better when it came to flying!

Comment: Are PS3 controllers working with GTA:SA? You can connect them to android. And they have two analog sticks

Comment: I am not sure about android as i no longer have an android tablet, so can't test it but i used to play gta 3 on my ipad with a controller

Comment: Horrible choice by the game developers. Beyond not being able to control both axis (available in the original game), but they put the turn controls where you typically use analog. If you try moving forward, you may accidentally turn instead... It's like UX was not a concept to them. I no longer play since it's just not worth spending hours upon hours on a mission due to Rockstar needing our ability to control. Controls are #1 in a game, and they messed it up beyond playable.

Answer (score 0):

The controls on flying with the analog stick are very hard to master and can be very frustrating. I thought turning the sensitivity up or down would help but found the same result of crashing or overcorrecting my movements. The best way in my opinion is to give it enough gas to get in the air then keep it off unless I need to give it gas like to get higher and when it comes to steering move it in slight  and quick movements. Because holding it longer will make you go all over the place and miss coronas like in flight school or the plane races. Keeping your finger off the accelerator will make it slower and give you move control. I hope this helps alot.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of controllers you can use — I have an Ipega, which works pretty well. But you can also use a PS3 controller, although it requires a couple of things: there is a Sixaxis tool you have to download (requires root), but it's not compatible with all android devices — there's a Sixaxis compatibility checker on Play Store to verify whether it will work with your device.